# What data structure to use for this data?

Tags: python, class, design-patterns, data-structures

I'm very new to data structures and I'd really like to know the opinion of the experienced heads here at SO. I have some data which is hierarchical, basically like a tree. I used to store it in ordered points (x,y) stored as arrays but now it's becoming increasingly cumbersome to do this.

Let's say that I have two properties, on and off. For each property, I want to store 5 data values. But each of those data values has a corresponding data value which needs to be stored with it. I need to be able to plot these easily too.

I thought of a dictionary of tuples but it doesn't really work too well, particularly when it comes to plotting the values easily.

Any ideas?

---

An example is this. Say I have 3 balls, of mass 5, 10 and 15kg. I throw each ball with a range of velocities, say 1m/s, 2m/s, 3m/s, 4m/s and 5m/s. I measure the height for each ball and each velocity. So each velocity point is coupled to the corresponding height.

I used to store this in different arrays, say something like this:

ball_5kg:

```
v5=[1,2,3,4,5]
h5=[h1,h2,h3,h4,h5]
```

ball_10kg

```
v10=[1,2,3,4,5]
h10=[h1,h2,h3,h4,h5]
```

but I don't think if this is really ideal, or the best way to store this data, particularly when the number of ball masses and velocities get really large. Are there any better ways to store this?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the use case: Is your data strictly hierarchical, with 10 data points? Please give an example of how you have been storing it, and how it needs to change.

Comment: It will be a lot easier for people to help you if you can give some example of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do is something like this?

```
data = [
  { # OFF
    'val0': 'data0',
    'val1': 'data1',
    'val2': 'data2',
    'val3': 'data3',
    'val4': 'data4',
  },
  { # ON
    'val5': 'data5',
    'val6': 'data6',
    'val7': 'data7',
    'val8': 'data8',
    'val9': 'data9',
  }
]

data[0] # the `off` dict
data[1] # the `on` dict

list( data[0].keys() ) # ['val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']
list( data[1].keys() ) # ['val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8', 'val9']

data[0]['val0'] # 'data0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data appears to be multi-dimensional, rather than hierarchical (i.e. like matrix rather than like a tree) and it could be represented either using nested containers or objects in one container.

Example of nested containers:

```
container = {
    "ball_5kg" : ((1, h1), (2, h2), (3, h3), (4, h4), (5, h4)),
    "ball_10kg" : ((1, h1), (2, h2), (3, h3), (4, h4), (5, h4))
}
```

Example of objects in one container:

```
class DataPair():
    __init__(self, velocity, height):
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.height = height
class DataSeries()
    __init__(self, name, series):
        self.name = name
        self.series = series
container = [
    DataSeries("ball_5kg", (DataPair(1, h1), DataPair(2, h2), DataPair(3, h3), DataPair(4, h4), DataPair(5, h4)))
    DataSeries("ball_10kg", (DataPair(1, h1), DataPair(2, h2), DataPair(3, h3), DataPair(4, h4), DataPair(5, h4)))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your description of your data, but a tree is easily represented recursively.  Symbolically, Tree := [Node, [Tree]].  That is, a tree is a list whose first element is the root, and whose second element is a list of trees, namely the subtrees (children) of the root.  Alternatively, you could write Tree := [Node, Tree_1, Tree_2, ... Tree_N].

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use pickle and customized class. You can write your own setter and getter in class.